# Apache Shiro, permission control from database

Tags: java, security, shiro

I need to implement a security framework in a desktop application that I'm developing to control authentication and user permission control. I've heard that Shiro is an easy and flexible framework to work with. Unfortunately I've only encountered web based application examples.

What I'm looking for is how to retrieve permissions levels and users from a database and then use them with Shiro. Has anyone developed something like this before, or know any tutorial that I could check? I need an idea of how to structure my database tables, and how to read permissions with Shiro.

Comment: Have you done any research on the topic? You're much more likely to get answers if you show that you've made some effort yourself.

Comment: Honestly I only needed a hint on where to start, and all you could do was down vote the question (and then close it) instead of giving me a hint on how to address the situation I was trying to explain, at least @Sotirios Delimanolis answer was somehow useful as I had something to start on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shiro` does not concern itself with what your User model looks like. It provides interfaces, namely `Subject` and `Realm`, and its children `AuthenticatingRealm` and `AuthorizingRealm`, for interacting with that model in whichever way you want.

A custom implementation of  `AuthenticatingRealm` will implement the `doGetAuthenticationInfo`, in which you use your user model to create an `AuthenticationInfo` object that holds the authentication information for a `principal` or user.

You would do a similar action for authorization. Calling `Subject#isPermitted(String)` will, further down the stack, check an `AuthorizationInfo` object for authorization information which you retrieved from your database or other source (xml, plain text, etc.).

So just implement your own `AuthenticatingRealm` and `AuthorizingRealm` (possibly in same class) and register them with the `SecurityManager`.